Launching a ROS2 node from a lambda
I have some c++ code that runs on Linux and has no knowledge of ROS2. There is a need for updating an atomic variable in this project (e.g. a speed value) and I thought that since this value is present in a ROS2 topic running on  machine on the same network I could update this atomic value using the callback of a ROS2 node launched from a piece of code in the c++ project without adding a direct ROS2 dependency. I attempted to do that by creating a dynamic library (using colcon) which had the following function implementation (along with the appropriate header file).
std::function<void()> create_atomic_function(std::atomic<float> &atomic_variable)
{
    return [&atomic_variable]()
    {
        std::cout << "In the ROS launch func" << std::endl;
        rclcpp::init(0, nullptr);

        auto node = std::make_shared<rclcpp::Node>("atomic_node");

        auto callback = [&atomic_variable](const std_msgs::msg::Float32::SharedPtr msg)
         {
           std::cout << "Received value" << std::endl;
           atomic_variable = msg->data;
          };

          auto subscription = node->create_subscription<std_msgs::msg::Float32>(
                "atomic_topic", 10, callback);

          rclcpp::spin(node);

          rclcpp::shutdown();
        }
    };
}


When I try to launch this node using
int main (int argc, char** argv){
  std::atomic<float> speed;
  auto myFunction = create_atomic_function(speed);
  std::thread t(myFunction);
  t.detach();

  while(true)
  {
  }

  return 0;
}

while having included and linked with my .so and its header the code runs but the ros node is never launched and I see no evident errors. During my trials not even the first std::cout from the lambda is being printed in the console which I imagine means that the lambda is never ran. My question is then, is it possible to launch a ROS2 node this way, and if not, why?
